# meaning/form , using English

Tags: meaning

a beach wedding ***attended*** by Mrs Feeney's father...
In this sentence attended is a past participle part of a passive or adjective?

Comment: Typically, here at ELUSE we prefer the question's title to be specific to the question, versus being an attempt to categorise it - we have tags for categories.